# Is there an Infinite ammo and rapid fire command?

Tags: team-fortress-2

I like to mess around in TF2 practice, is there an infinite ammo and rapid fire command in TF2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/List_of_useful_console_commands

> `addcond 74` - Makes the player 10 times bigger and 10 times the health, also player will have infinite ammo but not clip size - player's melee range will remain the same

Comment: You will need cheats enabled to use addcond, which is accomplished with the following command: sv_cheats 1

Answer (score 1):

`enable sv_cheats 1`, use this command `alias regen "impulse 101; wait 1; regen"; regen`

Answer (score 1):

First of all, you have to be an admin of the server. You said you like messing around in practice, so thats technically being admin.

Then enable the developer console. You do this by going to Options → Advanced... → Enable developer console. You then want to bind a button to open the developer console; that's what you're gonna press.

Then, press the button you used to bind, and type in `sv_cheats 1`. `sv_cheats 1` basically enables cheat commands, which is what you're gonna use.

Then type in `addcond 72`. This command gives you slightly faster walking speed, rapid fire, and faster reload times. This command also gives infinite jump and more jump height.

And for infinite ammo, you could bind your other button to `impulse 101`.

Keep in mind that you will have to use this command again if you respawn, so you could maybe use an invulnerability command like `addcond 57`. Note that if you are invulnerable, you can't capture points or push carts.